# como programar el icono de ir atras del toolbar en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, toolbar

Es posible programar el icono de hacia atras del Toolbar? actualmente tengo la configuracion en el manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".CRUD.SintomaticoRespiratorio.NuevoSRActivity"
        android:label="Registro de SR."
        android:parentActivityName=".CRUD.SintomaticoRespiratorio.MenuAddoListSR"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Pero necesito regresar con unos variables  como si estuviera haciendo un  `intent`:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuAddoListSR.class);
    intent.putExtra("idEpisodioSR",idEpisodio);
    intent.putExtra("idPaciente",idPaciente);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

si es posible programarlo, el método normal que se emplea para volver a la actividad padre es así:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton); //para ver el boton back en toolbar
```

y en el `AndroidManifest.xml` así:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivitySecundaria"
            android:parentActivityName=".ActivityPrincipal">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ActivityPrincipal" />

<!-- Con ese meta-data le damos soporte a la modalidad de volver a la actividad padre en android anteriores a Lollipop -->
```

Acá puedes volver de una actividad a otra, pero si quieres cambiar el comportamiento de ese `back` en el `toolbar` tendrías que llamar al método `onSupportNavigateUp`, ejemplo:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        //... Codigo a implementar aca
        return true;
    }
```

Es decir que puedes hacer esto:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuAddoListSR.class);
       intent.putExtra("idEpisodioSR",idEpisodio);
       intent.putExtra("idPaciente",idPaciente); 
       startActivity(intent);
       return true;
    }
```

y de esta forma modificas el comportamiento del botón de la forma que desees.

NOTA: Si cambias el comportamiento del botón no es necesario agregar el código en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

Modificar la forma en que funciona el botón normal de ir atrás.

Supongo que en el onCreate() usas:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Para mostrar el botón de ir atrás.

Y además se captura el evento para volver al activity padre:

```
@Override 
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{ 
  switch (item.getItemId()) 
  { 
    case android.R.id.home: 
      NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); 
      return true; 
  } 
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
}
```

Esto seria lo normal, pero que tal si cambias:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

Por tu Intent normal:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuAddoListSR.class);
 intent.putExtra("idEpisodioSR",idEpisodio);
 intent.putExtra("idPaciente",idPaciente); 
 startActivity(intent);
```